# Configure GDB Logs to file

Tags: shell, gdb, gnu

How do I configure GDB to  overwrite file for every new command and new output result?

I have tried "set logging overwrite on", it only overwrite the existing file when I start gdb but when i run multiple commands the results append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is somewhat unreasonable, but you likely can achieve it using GDB [hooks](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html).

Untested:

```
define hook-print
  set logging off
  shell rm -f gdb.txt
  set logging on
end
```